# Как настроить .htaccess в веб приложении на Java Spring MVC

Tags: java, .htaccess, apache, spring-mvc, tomcat

подскажите как настроить доступ для администратора (хранить логин и пароль) к ГURL веб-приложения в .htaccess ?
есть веб приложение, написанное на Java с использованием Spring MVC.
Работаю в IDEA и для его запуска просто указываю путь к Томкату и WAR-ник, 
и приложение "деплоится" по адресу по типу локалхост:хххх и т.п.

Подскажите, как насторить админку для этого приложения с помощью .htaccess ?
в какой директории он должен лежать ,как его правильно сконфигурить и как приложени будет понимать , что логин и пароль нужно сверять с тем, что есть в этом файле ? как настоит логин страницу для этого ?

Я с ним еще не работала, 
Спасибо

про Спринг Секьюрити знаю, но мне нужно реализовать именно через .htaccess

Comment: apache htaccess и spring tomcat настолько вещи параллельные, что просто никак

Comment: Не как, тут нету такой возможности. Авторизацию, и распределение по ролям делаеться в данном случае только через *Spring Security*